# How do I get a word to appear when I hover over each of these images?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm new to HTML and CSS and have tried researching this problem but can't find anything works. I just want a simple word to appear when the mouse hover's over each individual picture. For example the first photo will have the word 'travel' appear either on the photo or just below it.

Here is the HTML:

```
div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_1_of_4">
    <a href="http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/sub%20pages/travel.html"> <img src="http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/portfolioresources/travel01.png" alt="View travel photography" height="200"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_4">
    <a href="http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/sub%20pages/wedding.html"> <img src="http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/portfolioresources/weddings01.png" alt="View wedding collection" height="200"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_4">
    <a href="http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/sub%20pages/people.html"><img src="http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/portfolioresources/people01.png" alt="View people photography" height="200"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_4">
    <a href="http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/sub%20pages/studio.html"><img src="http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/portfolioresources/studio01.png" alt="View studio photoshoot" height="200"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS

```
    /*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding-left:7px;
}


/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }
/*  GRID OF FOUR  */
.span_4_of_4 {
    width: 100%;
}
.span_3_of_4 {
    width: 74.6%;
}
.span_2_of_4 {
    width: 49.2%;
}
.span_1_of_4 {
    width: 23.8%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    .span_1_of_4, .span_2_of_4, .span_3_of_4, .span_4_of_4 { width: 100%; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
title="travel"
```

will use the browser's default tooltip display. For example,

```
<img src="http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/portfolioresources/travel01.png" alt="View travel photography" height="200" title="travel">
```

If you want more control, check out [jQueryUI's tooltip widget](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Answer (score 1):

Managed to figure it out with the help of @Ixe. By using the div class category, I was able to separate the 'a' attribute from other parts on my page. This effect for me made the text appear above the photo and make the photo push down. You can obviously adjust this effect to be more slick looking.

**Html:**

```
<div class="col span_1_of_4">
    <a href="sub pages/wedding.html"><div class="category"><h2>Wedding</h2></div><img src="portfolioresources/weddings01.png" alt="View wedding collection" height="200"></a>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.category {
    font-family:Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    color: #FADBC8;
    position:relative;

}
.category a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;

}

a div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

a:hover div {
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`:hover` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) to show/hide an element:

```
<a href="#">
    <div>Travel</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

a div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

a:hover div {
  display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cnyxqc41/

Comment: this is really good thankyou, however I can't do that because I need the href to link to another page therefore I can't have it has #. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Well, change it to whatever you want! Don't just copy-paste this code... adjust it to fit your need.

Comment: Yes I did try that.. That doesn't work because I have other things on my page using the 'a' tag. I tried putting a class on the a too and that did not work

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Maybe change the css to select a more inclusive selector. Add an id to your div, then select "#my-id a" to limit the selection to only the links in the div.

Comment: no worries managed to sort it using as you said, a class to the div. Many thanks